# How to block user from entering URLs in text box in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 2 and I want to restrict the user from entering URLs and links in the text box. 
Can we use regular expression for this ?

Comment: There is no such thing as angular JS 2

Comment: To clarify @AamirKhan's comment - AngularJS refers to version 1.x, Angular refers to version 2.x and above (yes, it's a confusing naming convention).

Comment: @AamirKhan Yes I am using Angular version 2.0

Comment: You can use a directive that checks any input for being a URL. You can use a regex for this. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/2227788

Comment: @AamirKhan I have used this    pattern="[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)"   but still itis taking all the comments

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @AamirKhan Thanks Dude, Now its working

Comment: @debashishdwivedi You're welcome. If my answer has resolved your question then please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @AamirKhan  Actually I have only 1 Reputation so I cant do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a directive to monitor the input in your textbox. The directive can use a Regular Expression to check if the current input is a URL or not. Here's an example

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUrlBlocker]'
})
export class UrlBlockerDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  regex = new RegExp(this.expression);

  @HostListener('keyup') check() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.value.match(this.regex)) {
      alert('You have entered a URL!');
      // Remove entered content
      this.el.nativeElement.value = '';
    } else {
      console.log('Does not match');
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it on your input like so

```
<input appUrlBlocker type="text" placeholder="No URLs allowed" />
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3dxgpt)